# How do I match a regex provided that the word after my reg is not equal to a certain string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

I'm using Rails 5 and Ruby 2.4.  I'm confused about how to match a regular expression in which the word following is not equal to a certain thing.  I want to match a number, a "/" and another number provided that the word after is not equal to "aaa".  So this would match

```
1/3 ddd
```

as would

```
7/10 eee
```

and also

```
33/2
```

but not

```
4/555aaa
```

or

```
4/5 aaa
```

I have figured out how to craft my regex this far ...

```
2.4.0 :006 > re = /\d+[[:space:]]*\/[[:space:]]*\d+/
 => /\d+[[:space:]]*\/[[:space:]]*\d+/
...
2.4.0 :009 > string = "1/2 aaa"
 => "1/2 aaa"
2.4.0 :010 > string.match(re)
 => #<MatchData "1/2">
```

but I don't know how to add the clause about "the last word shall not be 'aaa'".  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sugges using a negative lookahead `(?![[:space:]]*aaa)` combined with a possessive `++` quantifier after last `\d`:

```
/\d+[[:space:]]*\/[[:space:]]*\d++(?![[:space:]]*aaa)/
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/GpWjtZS9oK)

**Details**

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `[[:space:]]*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\/` - a forward slash
- `[[:space:]]*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\d++` - 1 or more digits, matched possessively, so that the negative lookahead that follows could not make the engine backtrack into this subpattern (and yield a smaller portion of digits that are not followed with the lookahead pattern)
- `(?![[:space:]]*aaa)` - the negative lookahead that fails the match if there is no 0+ whitespaces and `aaa` immediately to the right of the current location.